# why do we need page cache when there is virtual memory

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

simple question about os. I know virtual memory handle the memory mapping for us. When some data we need is not in memory, VM will page in and copy the data into main memory, and if we are short of memory it will also page out some obsolete memory to disk. My question is, since virtual memory already handle this, why do we need a page cache? It seems to me VM already make main memory a cache for disk.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory: see all address space (ram) as my own and bigger than the actual memory (swap to disk as necessary);

Page cache: open a file that is stored in some drive (a filesystem thing)